How to calculate taxable portion of non-qualified 529 distribution?
Due to the well-known unpredictability of college pricing, I am trying to work out all of the possible tax scenarios for 529 savings. Websites generally say that the "gains" are taxable when I make a non-qualified distribution. But what portion of the "gains" is included in each distribution?
Suppose I contributed $100K to a California 529, and – a few years later – $100K to a Kansas 529 with the same beneficiary.
Now let's say, after some ups and downs in the market, the California 529 is worth $120K and the Kansas 529 is still worth $100K.
Scenario 1: Let's say I use the entire California 529 for $120K of qualified educational expenses, and use the entire Kansas 529 to pay off $100K of my mortgage. What portion of my $100K non-qualified distribution from the Kansas plan is taxable?
Scenario 2: Let's say I use $20K of the California 529 for qualified educational expenses and use the remaining $100K of the California 529 plan to pay off the mortgage. What portion of the $100K non-qualified distribution from the California plan is taxable?
Update
This currently unanswered question regards a scenario similar to Scenario 1 above, and additionally asks whether the beneficiary designation affects the result.

[DISCLAIMER: Not professional tax advice, but someone who has used 529s extensively]
From a Federal standpoint, the breakdown by state does not matter. Your 529 withdrawals are seen as one big bucket.  The difference by state would be if there are any state income ramifications (e.g. Kansas has a state income tax deduction for contributions and I suspect would have state income tax ramifications for non-qualified distributions)
For Federal, my reading of the rules is that the earnings portion (prorated to the non-qualified portion of overall distribution) of a non-qualified withdrawals are subject to federal income tax and a 10% penalty.
In your case, 54.55% (120/220) of your withdrawal would be considered "taxable", and that portion of the overall earnings (54.55% of 20k or $10,901) would be added to your taxable income" AND subject to a 10% penalty.
If you received a Kansas Income Tax deduction for the contributions, I strongly suspect that the non-qualified earnings AND contribution would be considered income, and likely a penalty as well.
Bottom line - just like using a retirement account for anything other than retirement, it's generally a very bad idea to use 529 (which is an "Education IRA) contributions for anything other than education expenses. Consider keeping them to use for grandchildren or other beneficiaries instead of taking the tax/penalty hit.

Re: "it's generally a very bad idea to use 529 (which is an Education IRA) contributions for anything other than education expenses." It might be a bad idea, but it's also hard to avoid, given the unpredictability of college pricing. So we need to be able to understand how it will work.

This link confirms that all distributions must include a portion of earnings: "unlike a Roth IRA,
you must withdraw a portion of earnings with every 529 plan distribution." However this webpage calculates earnings per account, with each account independently generating its own 1099-Q. Can you support your claim that all the 529 accounts are treated as one big bucket?

For example, for scenario 1, I could use the California 529 this year for education expenses, and there is nothing to report. Then next year I could use the Kansas 529 to pay the mortgage, and if there are still no earnings in that account then the 1099-Q will show no earnings. And that is the only 1099-Q that I'll have that year.

My main support is that the IRS forms make absolutely no mention of separating accounts by state, and there are bulletins that address some of these potential loopholes. For scenario 1, I believe the spirit of the law would treat all accounts as one and you would technically only use a portion of the earnings to "pay for education expenses" in year one, since you should include the KS account when the earnings are prorated. It may not get reported that way but the IRS will determine if what is reported is what you can actually claim.

As I disclaimed I am not a tax professional so someone may have an answer that supports your plan better but my reading of the law tells me that you can't pick and choose accounts to use all of the growth on qualified expenses (just like Roth IRAs)
